# Determine the closest free set of X/Y coordinates within an ever expanding 2D grid stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm, math

I have a very basic MySQL table in which X and Y coordinates are stored for tiles within a grid. The center of the grid is 0,0 and tiles can be created in any direction. If the coordinates exists in the MySQL table, they are considered "taken".

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| tile_id | position_x | position_y |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 |          0 |          0 |
|       2 |          1 |          0 |
|       3 |          0 |          1 |
|       4 |          1 |          1 |
|       5 |         -1 |         -1 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

I need to place a set of 4 tiles (as a square, not a rectangle) into the grid in the closest possible position to 0,0.

To illustrate - the green tiles below would need to be found.

[image]

Sadly, I'm not even sure where to start with this one :(

Comment: "the closest" means the corner of that green squere ?

Comment: The closest unit of 4 tiles that are not already occupied, so in the image, it would be 4 tiles with a starting position of 0,-2

Comment: The problem seems quite challenging; in the meantime try to explain precisely how would you define "closest rectangle": by the distance of its more distant point? by the sum of the distances of the points? [And I hope that we are talking about the Manhattan distance).

Comment: Yes, Manhattan distance is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: 1) Must it be solved with MySQL/SQL? Will this query be dumping the data into another language (such as PHP), and could that language handle parsing the data to find the squares?
2) What about ties? Which would win if `1,0` was empty? Or would you want both returned?

Comment: Preferably I'd like to keep it on the DB side since the grid will be growing without limits. This could cause problems parsing the results with middleware. Having said that, we are using Node,js, and if a solution can be found that achieves the desired results efficiently - even with a large dataset, I would have to consider it. Hybrid solutions (Node/SQL) are welcome too.

Comment: With regard to ties, either result (whichever returned first) is acceptable (LIMIT 1). It's really about find a space.

Comment: Regarding "closest", is it to the center point of the 2X2 shape, or the edge, and if the later, which edge?

Comment: As long as the 4 tiles fit it doesn't matter. Whichever works/is easiest.

Comment: Has it been considered to have a limit to the grid size? For instance, when we look at `(0, 0)` we can _visually_ see that there are (at least) two empty cells towards the left. However, the same isn't true for `(3, 1)` or `(3, 2)`, but it requires to make an assumption that the grid size is fixed. If there was no limit, one of the approaches can keep looking right indefinitely until 2 empty boxes (or even a square) were found.

Comment: Would a table containing all possible squares be ok to have ? one one table with every square (including black) and one with just the black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a single-query solution.

For any given square `t` on the grid, we can identify 8 possible 4-square tiles around it that may be empty:

[image: Possible empty tiles]

If none of the 4 possible tiles that include (0,0) are available, the closest available tile to (0,0) must be adjacent to an existing taken square (since for any available tile not adjacent to an existing taken square, we can find an available tile that is closer).

That means we can construct a query over the taken squares to calculate possible available tiles.

To check whether we have an available tile adjacent to square t, we can use a query like the following:

```
  SELECT t.x AS x1, t.y-2 AS y1, t.x+1 AS x2, t.y-1 AS y2, LEAST(ABS(x1),ABS(x2))+LEAST(ABS(y1),ABS(y2)) AS distance
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t1 ON (t.x = t1.x OR t.x+1 = t1.x) AND (t.y-2 = t1.y OR t.y-1 = t1.y)
  WHERE t1.tile_id IS NULL
```

This will determine the left, top, right and bottom coordinates, as well as the Manhattan distance from (0,0), of available tiles in the `t1` position relative to the taken squares.

Next we need a union of the available tiles in all 8 positions. We also need to check for the 4 possibly available tiles that include (0,0), since they're not necessarily adjacent to an existing taken square.

```
SELECT *, LEAST(ABS(x1),ABS(x2))+LEAST(ABS(y1),ABS(y2)) AS distance
FROM (
  SELECT t.x   AS x1, t.y-2 AS y1, t.x+1 AS x2, t.y-1 AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t1 ON (t.x   = t1.x OR t.x+1 = t1.x) AND (t.y-2 = t1.y OR t.y-1 = t1.y)
  WHERE t.y <= 0 AND t1.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x+1 AS x1, t.y-1 AS y1, t.x+2 AS x2, t.y   AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t2 ON (t.x+1 = t2.x OR t.x+2 = t2.x) AND (t.y-1 = t2.y OR t.y   = t2.y)
  WHERE t.x >= 0 AND t2.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x+1 AS x1, t.y   AS y1, t.x+2 AS x2, t.y+1 AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t3 ON (t.x+1 = t3.x OR t.x+2 = t3.x) AND (t.y   = t3.y OR t.y+1 = t3.y)
  WHERE t.x >= 0 AND t3.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x   AS x1, t.y+1 AS y1, t.x+1 AS x2, t.y+2 AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t4 ON (t.x   = t4.x OR t.x+1 = t4.x) AND (t.y+1 = t4.y OR t.y+2 = t4.y)
  WHERE t.y >= 0 AND t4.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x-1 AS x1, t.y+1 AS y1, t.x   AS x2, t.y+2 AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t5 ON (t.x-1 = t5.x OR t.x   = t5.x) AND (t.y+1 = t5.y OR t.y+2 = t5.y)
  WHERE t.y >= 0 AND t5.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x-2 AS x1, t.y   AS y1, t.x-1 AS x2, t.y+1 AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t6 ON (t.x-2 = t6.x OR t.x-1 = t6.x) AND (t.y   = t6.y OR t.y+1 = t6.y)
  WHERE t.x <= 0 AND t6.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x-2 AS x1, t.y-1 AS y1, t.x-1 AS x2, t.y   AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t7 ON (t.x-2 = t7.x OR t.x-1 = t7.x) AND (t.y-1 = t7.y OR t.y   = t7.y)
  WHERE t.x <= 0 AND t7.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.x-1 AS x1, t.y-2 AS y1, t.x   AS x2, t.y-1 AS y2
  FROM tiles t
  LEFT JOIN tiles t8 ON (t.x-1 = t8.x OR t.x   = t8.x) AND (t.y-2 = t8.y OR t.y-1 = t8.y)
  WHERE t.y <= 0 AND t8.tile_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 0 AS x1, -1 AS y1, 1 AS x2, 0 AS y2
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tiles
    WHERE (x = 0 OR x = 1) AND (y = -1 OR y = 0)
  )

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 0 AS x1, 0 AS y1, 1 AS x2, 1 AS y2
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tiles
    WHERE (x = 0 OR x = 1) AND (y = 0 OR y = 1)
  )

  UNION ALL

  SELECT -1 AS x1, 0 AS y1, 0 AS x2, 1 AS y2
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tiles
    WHERE (x = -1 OR x = 0) AND (y = 0 OR y = 1)
  )

  UNION ALL

  SELECT -1 AS x1, -1 AS y1, 0 AS x2, 0 AS y2
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tiles
    WHERE (x = -1 OR x = 0) AND (y = -1 OR y = 0)
  )
) z
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
```

For brevity I used `x` and `y` instead of `position_x` and `position_y`. I used UNION ALL for speed since it avoids checking for duplicate rows, we only need one after all. Another optimization is to only check for tiles to the right of `t` where x >= 0, below `t` where y >= 0, and so on. Indexes on the `x` and `y` columns should be crucial to performance.

I tested it with your example grid:

```
+---+---+---+---+---------+
| x1| y1| x2| y2| distance|
+---+---+---+---+---------+
|-2 |  0| -1|  1|        1|
+---+---+---+---+---------+
```

Comment: Wow. Can't say I fully understand the solution, but it works. Specifically, the "FROM dual" table seems to not really exist. To extrapolate on this, how would you apply this to get a 3x3 square?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table for more on the dual table. For 3x3 tiles, there's 12 possible positions around `t`, and 9 tiles involving (0,0), so it just requires a few additional carefully constructed subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

As the logic is quite involved, I will not attempt a unique SQL statement; I will use auxiliary tables instead. Of course, these may be replaced by derived tables if needed.

To begin with, let's assume that we have a `numbers` table with values 0, 1, 2, 3, ... (large enough).

```
drop table if exists numbers;
create table numbers (nr int);
insert numbers (nr) values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4);
```

From this populate a `points` table. This table holds the entire grid (or at least a sufficiently large rectangular subset of it which contains the (0,0) point).

```
drop table if exists points;
create table points (x int, y int);

insert points (x, y) 
select x.nr, y.nr from numbers x, numbers y 
union all select -x.nr, y.nr from numbers x, numbers y where x.nr <> 0 or y.nr <> 0
union all select x.nr, -y.nr from numbers x, numbers y where x.nr <> 0 or y.nr <> 0
union all select -x.nr, -y.nr from numbers x, numbers y where x.nr <> 0 or y.nr <> 0;
```

Next compute all possible 2x2 squares:

```
drop table if exists squares;
create table squares (x_lo int, y_lo int, x_hi int, y_hi int);

insert squares (x_lo, y_lo, x_hi, y_hi)
select a.*, b.* from points a join points b on a.x = b.x - 1 and a.y = b.y-1;
```

Finally, this query will find all empty squares and order them according to the sum of their points' distance from (0.0). By limiting the result to 1 the "best" square is returned:

```
select x_lo, y_lo, x_hi, y_hi
, abs(s.x_lo) + abs(s.y_lo) + abs(s.x_hi) + abs(s.y_hi) as total_distance
from squares s 
left join t on t.position_x between s.x_lo and s.x_hi 
    and t.position_y between s.y_lo and s.y_hi
where t.position_x is null
order by abs(s.x_lo) + abs(s.y_lo) + abs(s.x_hi) + abs(s.y_hi)
limit 1
;
```

Your original data is in the `t` table:

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (tile_id int, position_x int, position_y int);
insert t values (1,0,0),(2,0,1),(3,1,0),(4,1,1),(5,2,1),(6,2,2),
       (7,3,1),(8,3,2),(9,0,-1),(10,0,-2),(11,-1,-1),(12,-1,-2);
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PHSCF36819)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this, however, creating the `squares` table isn't practical in this situation - capacity needs to be infinite. I'm really hoping to find a solution that uses simple math to add 4 to the last 'taken' tile that is closest to 0,0.

Comment: I don't understand very well; for all practical applications the capacity cannot be infinite. [Otherwise your "taken" table should also have infinite capacity]. Perhaps is the approach not clear enough? The capacity is controlled by the `numbers` table, which can become as large as you wish.

Comment: On second thought, do you mean that you cannot store such a large table? I believe that MySql lets you create a table in memory, perhaps this could help. Otherwise perhaps you should consider heuristics.

Comment: The size of the table shouldn't matter - large is fine. When I say capacity, I mean potential capacity, not allocated. Think of it in a similar manner to auto-increment, except in this case, as opposed to incrementing by 1 in a linear fashion, the grid is incremented by 4 tiles in one of many directions.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below first calculates and puts the empty tiles into a new table.
That grid is limited to the lowest and highest points that the black tiles have.
Plus a margin of 2 tiles for good measure.

From those empty tiles, the square blocks are calculated via inner joins.
Because if an inner join fails to link to a tile that's not in the table, then it wouldn't be an empty square block anyway.

The block with the lowest distance to (0,0) gets on top because of the order by, thus chosen.

```
drop table if exists filled_tiles;
create table filled_tiles ( 
 tile_id int not null auto_increment, 
 position_x int not null, 
 position_y int not null, 
 primary key (tile_id), 
 index idx_pos_x_y (position_x, position_y)
);

insert into filled_tiles (position_x, position_y) values 
(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(-1,-1),
(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),
(-1,-2),(0,-2),(0,-1);

-- 
-- Calculating the edges of the 2D grid
-- 
select min(position_x)-2, min(position_y)-2, max(position_x)+2, max(position_y)+2 
into @x_min, @y_min, @x_max, @y_max
from filled_tiles;

drop table if exists tally;
create table tally (n int not null, primary key (n));
insert into tally (n) values (-9),(-8),(-7),(-6),(-5),(-4),(-3),(-2),(-1),(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

-- 
-- A table for the empty tiles
-- 
drop table if exists unfilled_tiles;
create table unfilled_tiles (x int not null, y int not null, INDEX idx_x_y (x, y));

insert into unfilled_tiles (x, y)
select X.n, Y.n
from (select n from tally where n between @x_min and @x_max) X
cross join (select n from tally where n between @y_min and @y_max) Y
left join filled_tiles t on (X.n = t.position_x and Y.n = t.position_y)
where t.tile_id is null;

select 
concat('(',u1.x,',',u1.y,'),(',u2.x,',',u2.y,'),(',u3.x,',',u3.y,'),(',u4.x,',',u4.y,')') as tile_blocks
from unfilled_tiles u1
join unfilled_tiles u2 on (u1.x+1 = u2.x and u1.y = u2.y) -- right of the tile
join unfilled_tiles u3 on (u1.x = u3.x and u1.y+1 = u3.y) -- above the tile
join unfilled_tiles u4 on (u1.x+1 = u4.x and u1.y+1 = u4.y) -- above and right of the tile
where u1.x < @x_max and u1.y < @y_max -- the tiles in the up and right edges of the grid can be ignored
order by (abs(u1.x+u4.x)+abs(u1.y+u4.y))/4.0 asc -- distance to 0,0
limit 1;
```

Result :

```
(-2,0),(-1,0),(-2,1),(-1,1)
```

A demo can be found [here](http://rextester.com/NZLT4350) on rextester.

And [here](http://rextester.com/ECYUI10915) is a MS SQL Server version.
With recursive SQL and CTE's, it's then possible to do this in a single query.